# 'An object was provided as `children` instead of a component' error in python-dash after a redirect from Location

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a MWE Dash app, with a button that leads to a other page:

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)


app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
    html.Div(id='page-content'),
])


def get_overview_page():
    page = html.Div([
        dcc.Link(
            html.Button('Neu', id='new_button',
                        style={'margin-left': '10px', 'width': '100px', 'height': '27px',
                               'fontSize': '16px'}),
            href='/new-entry'
        ),
        dbc.Tooltip(
            "A.",
            target="new_button", placement="top"
        )
    ], style={'width': '30%', 'margin-top': '10px', 'display': 'inline-block', 'text-align': 'left'})
    return page


# Update the index
@app.callback(Output('page-content', 'children'),
              [Input('url', 'pathname')])
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == '/new-entry':
        return html.Div()
    else:
        return get_overview_page()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8086, host='127.0.0.1')
```

I receive the following error, when I press the button and move the mouse afterwards.
The error doesn't make any sense to me. What is going on?

An object was provided as `children` instead of a component, string, or number (or list of those). Check the children property that looks something like:

> An object was provided as `children` instead of a component, string,
> or number (or list of those). Check the children property that looks
> something like: {   "1": {
> "props": {
> "is_open": false
> }   } }

What I tried:
When I remove the dbc.Tooltip the error vanishes, but I don't know what's going on and I need the Tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that it's caused by a race condition between the callback loading the new page and the client-side callback that closes the dbc tooltip (setting `is_open` to `false`). The page-switch callback finishes, updating the children of your page, effectively removing the tooltip from the DOM. The client-side callback then closes the tooltip, attempting to patch the non-existing child, causing the children to get corrupted with a partial component that only has `is_open`.

I filed https://github.com/facultyai/dash-bootstrap-components/issues/997 just now, as I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35524994)

Comment: But it's the Ro.oT-cause analysis :D

Comment: The only question I could find in the text above is "What is going on?". I answered it by providing a root cause analysis, and the ticket I linked even contains a workaround.

Why do you say it does not answer the question?